# How to link an image in widget to specified url?

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

Do you know on how to link an image from current widget and link it to specified url?

I've been searching for the solution in `Google`, could not found the exact solution.

Im now developing a simple widget.. Its really new for me, Im not really understand on how to use the AppWidgetProvider

My current widget is only displaying image which it will directly link to a website when user click it..

So, my question is, which of these should I use in AppWidgetProvider ?

As we know there are 4 of them..

- onDeleted(context)
- onDisabled(context)
- onUpdated(context)
- onReceived(context)

can u explain a bit more about it? and the steps for me to make the code for linking the image to website.

thanks friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed this won't work for `AppWidgets`. You should call `setOnClickPendingIntent()` on your `RemoteViews` instance, passing it the `ImageView` id and the following `PendingIntent` object:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);
```

[Here's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent%28int,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) the documentation for the method. Hope this helps.

Comment: tq Egor, at least i have an alternative here, thanks for giving me guideline.. :) totally new in widget..I'll do it asap an update to u later.. :) thanks egor

Comment: by the way @Egor, what do u mean by RemoteView?

Comment: @NadirahIbtisam, If I understood your issue properly, you're trying to start a browser Activity from an AppWidget, is it right?

Comment: yes Egor.. sorry for the late reply, do you have any tutorial regarding this? on how the image from widget link to web..

Comment: Currently, I could not create setOnClickPendingIntent(). I only got.. setOnClickListener() ...:(

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide id for the widget not drawable.

```
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bg);
```

Without id android cant identify the widget. And also note one thing that reference your widget in your xml file in which you provide event.